# Extend range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I have an excel file with a column that contains ranges of zip codes

[image]

I have almost 7000 ranges, and I want to extend so as to have 1 zip code per row. If possible keeping the according days and service but if not I would just be happy with the extended zips column

Comment: Which Excel version do you have?

Comment: Maybe you can ellaborate how the days should be distributed on the ZipCodes for each cell, explain how it ranges (min/max) are there any gaps in the numbers? And most of all, show what you have already tried

Comment: @Ike Excel 2021. They shared a great solution below, thank you for taking your time

Comment: @Razputine Yes I realized it was not very clear, I'll try to explain it better next time. Thanks for your time, someone shared a great answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Formula:**

[image]

In `E1`:

```
=REDUCE(A1:C1,ROW(A2:A6),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(z,INDEX(A:A,y),VSTACK(x,IFERROR(EXPAND(SEQUENCE(RIGHT(z,5)-LEFT(z,5)+1,,--LEFT(z,5)),,3),INDEX(A:C,y,{1,2,3}))))))
```

---

**PowerQuery:**

[image]

M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ZipCode", type text}, {"Days", Int64.Type}, {"Service", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",each [ZipCode], each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Numbers(Number.FromText(Text.Start([ZipCode],5)),1+Number.FromText(Text.Range([ZipCode],6))-Number.FromText(Text.Start([ZipCode],5))), each Number.ToText(_)),"|"),Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ZipCode"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value", {{"ZipCode", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "ZipCode"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ZipCode", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Maybe someone more experienced in PQ will be able to give a better solution.

Comment: I didn't even understand the question, sometimes here on top of knowing excel we need also read minds, :-). Great solution!